# Livewire emit not happening from one component to another

Tags: php, laravel, timer, laravel-livewire

I have 2 livewire components on a page for a simple timer and notification process in a Laravel 10 app (Livewire2). The components are called NotifyMe and JobTimer the timer functions as it should, i start the timer and a notification is added and shown on my page. If i click cancel the notification is removed so the Timer part does what i need it to do. However the notify me notification has a close button and clicking this closes the notification but doesn't cancel the timer. In my NotifyMe component i use this function

```
public function removeNotification($alertId)
    {
        $userAlert = UserAlert::with('notification')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('id', $alertId)
            ->first();

        if ($userAlert && $userAlert->notification->type === 'timer') {
            // Emit the event to the JobTimer component with the job number to cancel the correct timer
            $number = $userAlert->notification->job_number;
            $userAlert->delete();
            $this->emitUp( 'cancelTimerEvent', $number );

            logger("Notification removed: {$number}");
        } else {
            // Set is_read = 1 for the notification that is clicked.
            UserAlert::where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('id', $alertId)->update(['is_read' => 1]);
        }



        // Refresh the notifications after removing.
        $this->refreshAllNotifications();
    }
```

which as you can see has an emit for cancelTimerEvent. In my Timer component I have the following events

```
protected $listeners = [
        'cancelTimerEvent' => 'cancelTimerEvent',
        'timerRefresh'     => 'checkAndStartTimer'
    ];
```

and the cancelTimerEvent is this

```
public function cancelTimerEvent($jobNumber)
    {
        logger("Timer cancel started for job: {$this->job->number}");
        if ($this->running && $this->job->number === $jobNumber) {
            // Cancel the timer and reset any necessary properties.
            $this->cancelTimer();
            $this->emit('$refresh');

            logger("Timer canceled for job: {$this->job->number}");
        }
    }
```

when i start the timer and close the notification the timer is still running (it throws a 404 after it is polled due to the alert being removed) in my laravel.log I do not see the cancelTimerEvent logger messages and only see `[2023-08-03 15:15:35] local.DEBUG: Notification removed: 82387` so the event isn't handled.

I've spent hours on this today and achieved nothing than knowing the event isn't being received in the Timer. I even asked ChatGPT for help but it was more frustrating and non helpful than anything else.

Comment: You're using `emitUp`. Is the Timer a parent component of the Notification component? If not, then you're using the wrong event.

Comment: I had tried using emit but same issue. I have now refactored the entire thing and it does now work in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

So I refactored extensively ad took a different approach

```
    public function removeNotification($alertId)
    {
        $userAlert = UserAlert::with('notification')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('id', $alertId)
            ->first();

        if ($userAlert && $userAlert->notification->type === 'timer') {
            // ToDo leave me alone. This currently has no close so will be always open
        } else {
            // Set is_read = 1 for the notification that is clicked.
            $userAlert->update(['is_read' => 1]);
        }

        // Refresh the notifications after removing.
        $this->refreshAllNotifications();
    }
```

```
    public function cancelTimer()
    {
        $this->checkTimer();
        $this->running = false;
        $this->timeElapsed = 0;
        $roundedTimeElapsed = 0;
        // Remove the alert if there is one
        $alert = $this->alert;
        $alert->delete();
        $task = Task::find( $this->taskId );
        $task->delete();
        $this->emit( 'notifyMeRefresh' );

    }
```